# Is there a limit on the number of queries to Youtube?

Tags: python, youtube

I have a Python script that converts a YouTube video to mp3 file. Actually I tested on some videos and it works great.

Now, I will launch it on 300,000 youtube videos, and before I do that, I want to know if YouTube will authorize such an operation. Is there any limit for doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using a particular api?

Comment: no without any api

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly searching on YouTube, there is no limit.

While If you are searching through API, there is a daily limit. You can find the exact limit on Your API Console, regular quota for API usage is 1,000,000 units per day. You can apply for higher quota if you have some app that is more popular and requesting more units than it.

From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-YouTube-have-a-limit-to-the-number-of-videos-one-can-search)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but to be more specific i want to download video from Youtube. Is it possible using the API ?

Comment: It is against TOS, so the answer to your question is no.